# Programmatic navigation controller not visible?

Tags: swift

I am trying to embed a navigation controller in my app programmatically, but am unable to do so. I am at a loss because online tutorials are doing exactly what I am and still my navigation bar fails to show up.

My app delegate is as follows:

```
 var window: UIWindow?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.3965077436, blue: 0.2242108541, alpha: 1)

    return true
}
```

and my ViewController code is as follows:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationItem.title = "Navigation Controller"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Where am I making an error?

Comment: Use the same thing in `sceneDelegate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in `SceneDelegate`:

```
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    var rootVC = ViewController() //Your view controller

    self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

    let rootNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
    rooNC.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
    rootNC.navigationBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.3965077436, blue: 0.2242108541, alpha: 1)

    self.window?.rootViewController = rootNC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()        

}
```